# vf page,radio rendering

Tags: visualforce, radio-button

```
<apex:page standardController="Employee__c" extensions="testPage" tabStyle="Employee__c">

<apex:form id="frm1">

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="acc" checked="checked" value="Existing" onclick="pbBlockRenderJS('1');">Existing </input>



  <input type="radio" name="acc" value="NEWAcc" onclick="pbBlockRenderJS('2');">New</input>

  </div>




  <apex:pageBlock id="pb1" title="Pg Block 1" >
  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
 <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!saving}"/>
   </apex:pageBlockButtons>

   <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
   <apex:inputField value="{!pme.Name}"/>
   <apex:inputField value="{!pme.Address__c}"/>
      <apex:inputField value="{!pme.Phone__c}"/>

   </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>
<apex:outputPanel id="pnl1">

  <apex:pageBlock id="pb2" title="Pg Block 2" rendered="{!IF(mypbBlock == '2',true,false)}">
  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
 <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!saving}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>

   <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
   <apex:inputField value="{!pme.Name}" />
<apex:inputField value="{!pme.Job_Title__c}"/>
   <apex:inputField value="{!pme.Salary__c}"/>

   </apex:pageBlockSection>
  </apex:pageBlock>

  </apex:outputPanel>

  <apex:actionFunction action="{!pbBlockRender}" name="pbBlockRenderJS" rerender="pb2">

        <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!mypbBlock}" value="" />

    </apex:actionFunction>

</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

class

```
public with sharing class testPage {
public string Existing{get; set;}
public string NEWAcc{get; set;}

    public Employee__c emp{get;set;}
    public Employee__c pme{get;set;}
    public Employee__c emplist{get;set;}
    public String var {get;set;}
        public boolean editSection {get;set;}

        public testPage(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            Employee__c emp=new Employee__c();
            pme=(Employee__c )controller.getRecord();
            editSection =true;
            var= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
             system.debug('erecrrrtrtrt');

                system.debug('erecrrrtrtrt'+NEWAcc);
            if(var!=null){
            emplist=[select Name,Address__c,Phone__c,Job_Title__c,Salary__c  From Employee__c where id=:var];
            system.debug('id'+var);
            }
            }
        public PageReference saving(){
                        system.debug('erecrrrtrtrt'+Existing);

                system.debug('erecrrrtrtrt'+NEWAcc);
            upsert pme;
            PageReference p=new PageReference ('/'+pme.id);
            p.setRedirect(true);
            return p;
            }
    public PageReference pbBlockRender() {
    return null;
    }
    public PageReference EdittheSection (){
editSection = true;
return null;

        }

    public String mypbBlock { get; set; }
}
```

I have two radio buttons,by default Existing is selected so Pg Block 1 is displayed works fine but am not able to display Pg Block 2 when New radio is selected,please help me how to solve it..Iam a fresher.

Comment: please show the JS for the radio button onclick actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a reason to go back to the server when the radio buttons are clicked, you can do all the processing at the client-side using [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) to show or hide the page block found by using [getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp). This gives a more immediate response to the user's actions:

```
<apex:page id="p">
<apex:form id="f">
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="acc" value="Existing" checked="checked"
                onclick="show(true, false);">Existing</input>
        <input type="radio" name="acc" value="NEWAcc"
                onclick="show(false, true);">New</input>
    </div>
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb1" title="Pg Block 1">
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock id="pb2" title="Pg Block 2">
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>   
<script>
function show(showPb1, showPb2) {
    // Match Visualforce's prefixing pattern
    document.getElementById('p:f:pb1').style.display = showPb1 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('p:f:pb2').style.display = showPb2 ? 'block' : 'none';
}
show(true, false);
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi Sir,,I tried with your suggestion,,if i check the new radio button,it has to show only pb block2,,in our case pb block1 and pb block 2 both are displayed'

Comment: @sahi I was copying your Visualforce that did not appear to be trying to conditionally render pb block1. I've changed the code in the answer so both will be switched.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you cannot see the Pg Block 2 is that the following expression does not evaluate to 'true' :  `rendered="{!IF(mypbBlock == '2',true,false)`
In other words you are not setting the mypbBlock variable to 2 inside your testPage class.

Comment: The `apex:actionFunction` `assignTo="{!mypbBlock}"` in theory does set `mypbBlock` in the controller; can you explain a bit more?